# Correct preposition with container

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Help me please choose right preposition:

- Place **in** container.
- Place **at** container.

When you need to place something **inside** the container.

I aways have problems with prepositions, can you explain me please, how to use it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just answered yourself - **in**side the container! So, what did you use there? *'in.'*

When unsure, look up in some dictionaries. I use OALD, Collins and Cambridge. Check the **examples** and you'll surely learn it.

A couple for you -

> *Food will last longer if kept **in** an airtight container. ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/container?q=container))* 
>  *Biscuits will stay crisp if you keep them **in** an airtight container ([Cam](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/container)).*